# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object - nor is foreach looping properly

Tags: php, foreach, mysqli

For some reason I cannot for the life of me figure out/understand why this is not working properly...All I am trying to do is display comments on a photo page. The photo I am testing this on has 2 comments but all I get is the following:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/photo_gallery/public/photo.php on line 47
NULL @ ::
```

photo.php page is simply calling for the comments by the photo id and then displaying them in a foreach loop:

```
<?php
$photo = Photograph::findByID($_GET['id']);
$comments = $photo->comments();
printr($comments);
?>
<div class="comments">
<?php if ($comments): ?>
    <?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <?php echo htmlentities($comment->author); ?> @ <?php echo strip_tags($comment->created, '<strong><em><p>'); ?> :: <?php echo $comment->body; ?>
    </p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>No comments found.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

When I print_r on the $comments results, only the first comment shows up in the object array..

**Part of the Photograph class:**

```
class Photograph extends DatabaseObject {
    public $id;

     function comments() {
        return Comment::findCommentsOn($this->id);
    }
}
```

**Part of the MySQLiDatabase class:**

```
public static function findByPrepare($sql = "", $params) {
    global $db;
    $result = $db->query($sql, $params);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        printr($result);
        return self::instantiate($row);
    }
}

private static function instantiate($record) {
    $className = get_called_class();
    $obj = new $className;

    foreach ($record as $attribute => $val) {
        if ($obj->hasAttribute($attribute)) {
            $obj->$attribute = $val;
        }
    }
    return $obj;
}
private function hasAttribute($key) {
    // get_object_vars returns an assoc array with all attributes as keys and their current values as the value
    $objVars = $this->attributes();
    return array_key_exists($key, $objVars);
}

protected function attributes() {
    // return an array of attribute keys and their values
    $attributes = array();
    foreach(static::$dbFields as $field) {
        if (property_exists($this, $field)) {
            $attributes[$field] = $this->$field;
        }
    }
    return $attributes;
}
```

Seems like it is stemming from the foreach in the findByPrepare() function...

When I printr($result) it shows both comments in an array fine, however when I printr($row) it displays just the first comment in an array...so somehow I need to get $row to loop through each result. I have tried looping the self::instantiate($row) in an array but then that throws another error: **Fatal error: Call to a member function comments() on a non-object**

***print_r on $comments (this is only coming up with 1 result when there's actually 2 comments)***

```
Comment Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [photo_id] => 1
    [created] => 2013-12-20 16:37:02
    [author] => Nate
    [body] => This is a cool pic!
)
```

***var_dump($comment->author) displays***

```
NULL @ ::
```

***var_dump($comments) displays***

```
object(Comment)#4 (5) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["photo_id"]=> int(1) ["created"]=> string(19) "2013-12-20 16:37:02" ["author"]=> string(4) "Nate" ["body"]=> string(19) "This is a cool pic!" }
```

*The rest of the code that was requested:*

**Comments class:**

```
class Comment extends DatabaseObject {
    protected static $tableName = "comments";
    protected static $dbFields = array('id', 'photo_id', 'created', 'author', 'body');
    public $id;
    public $photo_id;
    public $created;
    public $author;
    public $body;

    public static function findCommentsOn($photo_id = 0) {
        $params = func_get_args();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ". self::$tableName ." WHERE photo_id = ? ORDER BY created ASC";
        $results = parent::findByPrepare($sql, $params);
        return $results;
    }
}
```

**MySQLiDatabase class:**

```
class MySQLiDatabase {
        public $conn;
        public $lastQuery;
        public $stmt;
        public $id;
        public $username;
        public $password;
        public $first_name;
        public $last_name;
        private $params;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->connection();
        }

        public function connection() {
            $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
            if ($this->conn->connect_errno) {
                return "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->conn->connect_errno . ") " . $this->conn->connect_error;
            }
        }

        public function query($sql, $params) {
            $this->lastQuery = $sql;
            $result = $this->prepareQuery($sql, $params);
            if ($params) { $this->bindParams($params, $this->stmt); }
            $this->stmt->execute();
            $results = $this->bindResults($this->stmt);

            return $results;
        }

        private function prepareQuery($sql, $params) {
            $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            $this->confirmQuery($this->stmt);
            return $this->stmt;
        }

        public function bindParams($params, $stmt) {
            $types = "";
            for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($params); $i++) {
                $types .= "s";
            }

            $array = array_merge(array($types), $params);
            return call_user_func_array(array($this->stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->refValues($array));
        }

        public function bindResults($stmt) {
            if ($stmt->affected_rows === -1) { // SELECT
                $meta = $this->stmt->result_metadata();
                $params = array();
                while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
                    $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
                }
                call_user_func_array(array($this->stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);

                $results = array();
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    $x = array();
                    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
                        $x[$key] = $val;
                    }
                    $results[] = $x;
                }
            } else { // INSERT UPDATE DELETE
                $results = $stmt->affected_rows;
            }
            return $results;
        }
```

Comment: CAn you supply a var_dump or print_r of the comments?

Comment: sure, updating the question right now.

Comment: It looks to me like you are iterating the indices, id, photo_id etc. and not actual comments. This is related to your comment that only one comment is being shown. I'm not sure what database layer you are using, but I am fairly sure the problem here is that the database is being told to return one row and not all rows.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's odd though that the printr($result) in the findByPrepare method is indeed printing out all of the comments though :/

Comment: Yes. This comment is stand-alone, i.e., the comment does not have an index like, 0. I cannto offer more help though as I cannot see where the database is saying only return one row. Show more code if you can find it.

Comment: Thanks, I will add the bits and pieces to the bottom in a moment when I get it all together, haha.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because StackOverflow is not a crowd-sourced debugging tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out!

First, what loushou mentioned was correct, however, there is a little bit more to it.

I was missing an array_shift in my findByID() method (I had not posted this in the original question, so sorry about that).

```
public static function findByID($id) {
    $params = func_get_args();
    $result = self::findByPrepare("SELECT * FROM ". static::$tableName ." WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1", $params);
    return !empty($result) ? array_shift($result) : false;
}
```

Without the array shift, it was putting the Photograph object in an array, therefore resulting in that "Fatal error: Call to a member function comments() on a non-object" error. Once I added the array shift, it seemed to fix everything! Thanks for the feedback all.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
public static function findByPrepare($sql = "", $params) {
  global $db;
  $result = $db->query($sql, $params);
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    printr($result);
    return self::instantiate($row);
  }
}
```

Your return is only ever returning a single row. Assumedly you want to return an array of all the results. What you need to do is this:

```
public static function findByPrepare($sql = "", $params) {
  global $db;
  $final = array();
  $result = $db->query($sql, $params);
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $final[] = self::instantiate($row);
  }
  return $final;
}
```

Once you make that change, your `$comments = $photo->comments();` line should return an array of comments, or an empty array. This will in turn make your `if ($comments):` actually work as you expect it to, and then your `foreach ($comments as $comment):` will loop over an actual array, instead of an object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! That's what I had tried, however that's when this error occurs instead "Fatal error: Call to a member function comments() on a non-object in" which is this line "$comments = $photo->comments();" on photo.php